# How to create a price change module | PrestaShop

Tags: php, module, prestashop

How to create a price change module in PrestaShop with a specified time interval to a certain price?

I need to create three fields for selecting a product or all products and choosing a time interval for price changes. In the third field, you can specify the price up to which to change, or you can leave it empty and change it to the minimum.

How to do it all?

I'm a newbie

Few understand how to do

Comment: Perhaps you need to create a new table in the database in goods and change prices from there.

Prices have to change constantly, until it becomes necessary.

Comment: Please check "Specific prices", it's the closest feature to what you want to achieve.
https://support.prestashop.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000482012-What-is-a-specific-price-

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to this is to create a module which would select all necessary products and manage their specific prices as a default feature does. In another way, it would be very difficult or even impossible to implement all related features. Because price calculation is going deep inside the core and you need rework it all. I mean, if you would create your own table and implementation it will be difficult to rework all carts calculation, statistic etc.